# dot notation in utplsql advanced data comparison

Tags: oracle, plsql, utplsql

I've come across the below code snippet in utPLSQL website.

```
procedure test_cur_skip_columns_eq is
  l_expected sys_refcursor;
  l_actual   sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_expected for select 'text' ignore_me, d.* from user_tables d;
  open l_actual   for select sysdate "ADate",  d.* from user_tables d;
  ut.expect( l_actual ).to_equal( l_expected ).exclude( 'IGNORE_ME,ADate' );
end;

procedure test_cur_skip_columns_cn is
  l_expected sys_refcursor;
  l_actual   sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_expected for select 'text' ignore_me, d.* from user_tables d where rownum = 1;
  open l_actual   for select sysdate "ADate",  d.* from user_tables d;
  ut.expect( l_actual ).to_contain( l_expected ).exclude( 'IGNORE_ME,ADate' );
end;
```

It has this line of code with dot notation, `ut.expect( l_actual ).to_contain( l_expected ).exclude( 'IGNORE_ME,ADate' );`. I read some oracle docs for the usage of dot notation and everywhere it says package_name.object_name or schema_name.table_name. But the above mentioned line of code doesn't look like any of these. I am interested to know what are those objects between each dots. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am interested to know what are those objects between each dots.

These are, indeed, [oracle objects](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjint.htm#ADOBJ001) (aka user-defined types, aka [abstract data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/about-oracle-objects.html#GUID-8F0BA083-FA6D-4373-B440-50FDDA4D6E90)).

```
ut.expect( l_actual ).to_contain( l_expected ).exclude( 'IGNORE_ME,ADate' );
```

What happens here:

- package [`ut`](https://github.com/utPLSQL/utPLSQL/blob/develop/source/api/ut.pks) contains a function named [`expect`](https://github.com/utPLSQL/utPLSQL/blob/develop/source/api/ut.pks#L34) that returns an object of type `ut_expectation_compound`;
- [`ut_expectation_compound`](https://github.com/utPLSQL/utPLSQL/blob/develop/source/expectations/ut_expectation_compound.tps) is a type that defines two member functions: [`to_contain`](https://github.com/utPLSQL/utPLSQL/blob/develop/source/expectations/ut_expectation_compound.tps#L33) and [`exclude`](https://github.com/utPLSQL/utPLSQL/blob/develop/source/expectations/ut_expectation_compound.tps#L40). Both of them return `ut_expectation_compound` which allows the method calls to be chained like this.

You might want to read the [Object-Relational Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/preface.html#GUID-5CC9B2C2-D699-45B2-B9C7-798442489ADD) to get an introduction into the topic. Also read [PLSQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/preface.html#GUID-9952D28D-0310-4869-8002-4462BDC679BB) - it should provide an answer for most of your questions about PLSQL syntax.